# 'use of "text-field" requires a style "glyphs" property' when using a plain background

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using a plain background, rather than using a MapBox style, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42522779/906814)

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: {
      version: 8,
      sources: {},
      layers: [
        {
          id: 'background',
          type: 'background',
          paint: {'background-color': 'white'}
        }
      ]
    }
});
```

I've added a `GeoJSON` point layer and I'm trying to label it:

```
'layout': {
  'text-field': ['get', 'name'],
  'text-font': ['Open Sans Semibold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
},
```

If I use a standard MapBox style for the map, the layer is correctly labelled. But if I use the aforementioned blank basemap, this layer returns the error:

> use of "text-field" requires a style "glyphs" property

[Searching](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4808) this error message shows that I need to add a `glyphs` option:

`"glyphs":"mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"` or `"glyphs":"https://fonts.openmaptiles.org/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf"`

However, neither of these options prevents the error message, and the layer is not labelled.

What is the correct syntax for the `glyphs` parameter when using an empty basemap?

Answer (score 3):

I copied this for my style option and it worked fine with no errors when I previously had the same error as you:

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "Empty",
  "metadata": {
    "mapbox:autocomposite": true
  },
  "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "sources": {},
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "background",
      "type": "background",
      "paint": {
        "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles/blob/master/styles/empty-v8.json

Comment: thanks for the tip. I haven't worked on this project for a while so I'll take another look when time permits. Perhaps MapBox previously had a bug which they've since fixed?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I created a new Blank style in MapBox Studio and used that as the basemap. After this, the labels appeared correctly.

[image]

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  style: mapbox://styles/my-blank-map,
  ...
})
```

I'd still like to know if there's a programmatic way to do this using the MapBox GL-JS API though.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this error when I accidentally attempted to set my map's style to `undefined`. The problem went away when I fixed the bug and instead provided a legitimate `mapbox://` style URL.